# Rails 4 + Paperclip: Making a default profile picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

Our profile view page has the code presented. We've tweaked it a few times with examples shown with similar issue, but have yet to get an outcome where the picture is present. Currently we get "Missing Pic" to be shown in the area where the default picture should be showing.

```
<% if @user.avatar.present? %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
<% else %>
<h4>Missing Pic</h4>
<% end %>
```

Our User model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
:medium => "200x200>",
:small => "150x150#",
:thumb => "100x100",
:default_url => "/assets/images/missing.png"
}
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

In our show users view we have

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:small) %>
```

Path shown in Develop tools are:

right now we have our missing image in "/app/assets/images/missing.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Paperclip::Attachment#file?`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L348) (for which [`Paperclip::Attachment#present?`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L352) is an alias), as well as [`Paperclip::UrlGenerator#most_appropriate_url`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/url_generator.rb#L31)

The avatar isn't present until the user submits their own file, but the `#url` method will return the default URL when the avatar isn't present. If you remove the `@user.avatar.present?` check and the "Missing Pic" header so that your view code is just:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

the default image will render when the user hasn't uploaded an avatar.